# Waiting for running Reactor Mono instances to complete

Tags: project-reactor, spring-webflux

I wrote this code to spin off a large number of WebClients (limited by `reactor.ipc.netty.workerCount`), start the Mono immediately, and wait for the all Monos to complete:

```
   List<Mono<List<MetricDataModel>>> monos = new ArrayList<>(metricConfigs.size());
   for (MetricConfig metricConfig : metricConfigs) {
        try {
            monos.add(extractMetrics.queryMetricData(metricConfig)
                  .doOnSuccess(result -> {
                      metricDataList.addAll(result);
                  })
                  .cache());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    Mono.when(monos)
          .doFinally(onFinally -> {
              Map<String, Date> latestMap;
              try {
                  latestMap = extractInsights.queryInsights();
                  Transform transform = new Transform(copierConfig.getEventType());
                  ArrayList<Event> eventList = transform.toEvents(latestMap, metricDataList);
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  log.error("copy: mono: when: {}", e.getMessage(), e);
              }
          })
          .block();
```

It 'works', that is the results are as expected.

Two questions:

1. Is this *correct*? Does `cache()` result in the `when` waiting for all Monos to complete?
2. Is it *efficient*? Is there a way to make this faster?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should try as much as possible to:

- use Reactor operators and compose a single reactive chain
- avoid using `doOn*` operators for something other than side-effects (like logging)
- avoid shared state

Your code could look a bit more like

```
List<MetricConfig> metricConfigs = //...
Mono<List<MetricDataModel>> data = Flux.fromIterable(metricConfigs)
    .flatMap(config -> extractMetrics.queryMetricData(config))
    .collectList();
```

Also, the `cache()` operator does not wait the completion of the stream (that's actually `then()`'s job).

Comment: `when` also waits for all its `Mono` sources to complete. still you are correct that `cache()` has nothing to do with that, and since the `Mono` resulting from the `cache` call is only visible to `when`, it serves no purpose IMO